# Check module version

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, version, require

I need to check if a module is of a certain version.

I can check if the module exists in the same folder by doing this:

```
var other;
try {
  other = require("../theOtherModule");
} catch(e){
  // module doesn't exist or something
}
```

However, this doesn't tell me the version of that module. I need to be able to tell if that module is of a certain version or higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in function that does this. Instead, you can get the version from the package.json file:

```
var packageJson = require('./package.json');
console.log(packageJson.version);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to have your module export its version so that other things can read it.

#### theOtherModule.js

```
exports.version = require('./package').version;
```

Then use the `semver` module, and assuming you required version `2.x` for example, but any version string that you might have in a `package.json` dependency list would work.

```
var semver = require('semver');
var other;
try {
    other = require("../theOtherModule");
} catch(e){
    // module doesn't exist or something
}

if (!semver.satisfies(other.VERSION, '2.x')){
     // Do whatever you need to do if the version isn't supported.
}
```

That said, it is important to realize that you are essentially duplicating the work on `npm` here, and this likely points to incorrect usage of node's module system. In cases where versioning is critical, it may be better to have an internal `npm` registry, and then simply have `theOtherModule` be an actual `npm` dependency.

Comment: Except I want to add features based on whether certain other, 3rd-party modules are installed.

Comment: Optional peer dependencies are a pain point in the community since they rely on untracked side-effects. If you want optional functionality, it would be better to have optional flag, or split your logic into one main module and other modules that explicitly use those other dependencies.

Comment: I'm not going to split my code when I could do the same with three lines.